# Calling FBSDKGameRequestContent: receiving the invite but not the notification in Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm sending a Game Request Content with something like this:

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
gameRequestContent.message = @"My message";
gameRequestContent.title = @"My title";
gameRequestContent.recipients = @[idFacebook];
gameRequestContent.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeNone;
FBSDKGameRequestDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
dialog.delegate = self;
[dialog show];
```

And the recipient can see the invite through https://www.facebook.com/games/activity but not receiving the notification in the top right facebook icon. Why is that?

In the Facebook App I've created the iOS app and the canvas game.

Comment: When notifications are shown only on mobile is because your App is just set up for mobile, not as a canvas App. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3#scenarios) I would suggest to double check your App settings. Can you access your canvas link https://apps.facebook.com/yourappname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your app public before anyone could watch the notification on their iPhones.